# how to make delphi timetostr return military time

Tags: delphi, datetime, delphi-7

I'm working on a legacy Delphi 7 program. When I call

```
timetostr(now)
```

I get a time string in 12 hour format complete with the 'AM' or 'PM' trailer.

I looked in help doc in the Delphi 7 and did a search on the internet. The results were kind of vague.

Comment: I don't know "miltary time" but `System.SysUtils.FormatDateTime` is quite flexible.

Comment: You can also use [SysUtils.DateTimeToString(Result,'hh:nn:ss',now)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.DateTimeToString)

Comment: For bonus point it needs to convert times before sunrise into "Oh dark hundred"

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, how is that implemented above the arctic circle? In summer time the sun is up all the time, while in winter, it never goes up.

Comment: Summertime:  No dark hundred.  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock) Military Time is the regular 24 hour clock.

In order to display that in Delphi you can use `FormatTime`. To be precise:

```
FormatTime('hh:mm:ss', now)
```

If you want milliseconds as well then

```
FormatTime('hh:mm:ss.zzz', now)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use TFormatSettings-variable:

```
var
  AFormat: TFormatSettings;
...
GetLocaleFormatSettings(-1, AFormat);
AFormat.ShortTimeFormat := 'hh:mm';
AStr := TimeToStr(Now, AFormat);
```

Comment: Probably not in Delphi 7

Comment: there are other properties in TFormatSettings, maybe you should use  LongTimeFormat instead of ShortTimeFormat

Answer (score 0):

This will do in recent Delphi versions

```
FormatDateTime('hh:mm:ss', now)
```